# Eddington's measurement and dark matter

Tags: general-relativity, dark-matter, gravitational-lensing

On May 29th 1919 Eddington measured a shift in starlight that confirmed a General Relativity prediction. The results were duplicated two times, once by the Lick observatory and again by Yerkes observatory. Yet, none of these measurements considered dark matter. How is it possible to get a correct lensing measurement and not consider dark matter?

Comment: Considering that dark matter has not yet been detected in the solar system by its influence on the results of experiments on the deflection of light rays by the Sun’s gravity is small and can be neglected.

Comment: When you have questions like this the usual procedure is to compare the expected scale of the two effects. As long as one effect is much larger than the other, an experiment just sensitive enough to pick up the larger needn't worry about the smaller (which will be swamped in experimental noise). Only when you measurement begins to achieve sensitivity comparable to the smaller effect do you start worrying.